# Rearrange columns with CSS when utilizing mobile first

Tags: html, css

How would I go about if I'm aiming to use pure HTML and CSS to achieve the results as shown in the below image?

[image: Rearranged css columns]

I need to rearrange the stacked elements for larger screens, I've tried with:

```
#2: float: left
#1: display: inline-block
#3: float: right
```

but that didn't do the trick. Anyone can point me in the right direction?

Comment: Are you fine with @media queries? Your image says >300px, so they can be suitable...

Comment: I don't know the exact answer, but CSS grid could do this. It looks complicated, but after a 15 minute tutorial you should be able to make this happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the easiest and neatest result, and also, to make use of the latest technology and trend - use [flexbox](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp). Specifically, follow [implementation of the Holy Grail with flexbox](https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/holy-grail/). For example - expand the below snippet, run it and resize the window:

```css
.HolyGrail {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.HolyGrail-body {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}
.HolyGrail-content {
  background-color:orange;  
  order:1;
}

.HolyGrail-content, .HolyGrail-ads {
  /* 12em is the width of the columns */
  flex: 0 0 300px;
}

.HolyGrail-nav {
  /* put the nav on the left */
  flex:1;
  order: -1;
  background-color:green;  
}
.HolyGrail-ads {
  background-color:red;
  order:3;
}
.HolyGrail,
.HolyGrail-body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .HolyGrail-body {
    flex-direction: row;
    flex: 1;
  }
  .HolyGrail-content {
    flex: 1;
  }
  .HolyGrail-content, .HolyGrail-ads {
    /* 12em is the width of the columns */
    flex: 0 0 300px;
  }
  .HolyGrail-nav {
    order:2;
  }
}
```

```html
<body class="HolyGrail">
  <div class="HolyGrail-body">
    <main class="HolyGrail-content">…</main>
    <nav class="HolyGrail-nav">…</nav>
    <aside class="HolyGrail-ads">…</aside>
  </div>
  <footer>…</footer>
</body>
```

Comment: While answers are always appreciated, please [**summarise your link's points**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) in your answer itself. The link to the page could [**break in the future**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot), which might detract from your answer. In fact, answers that are little more than a link [**may be deleted**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers). A few sentences or some sample code covering the key points from your link would make it so that your answer remains sound, even if the link no longer works :)

Comment: How does flexbox stand in old browsers? For me browser compability is crucial. Is there any fallback solution for old browsers or how would I tackle this given that I want browser compability?

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=flex All I see here is the green light. Beware of the IE bugs, tho, they are listed in the "Known issues" section.